# Make the titles centered using the titlesec package

Tags: sectioning, horizontal-alignment, titlesec

I am using the `titlesec` package to better define my section headings. I have a question about it: How can I make the titles already centered in the middle of the page? I have them centered (at the top of the page) at the moment with the following code :

```
\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\Large\bfseries\centering}{\thesection}{1em}{}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is that what you want?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[
            showframe,
            ]{geometry}

\titleformat{\section}
{\vspace*{\fill}\centering\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
{\thesection}
{1em}
{\Large}
[\vspace*{\fill}\newpage]

\begin{document}
  \section{First of all}

    \lipsum[1]

  \section{Second of all}

    \lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]